# Why does text input continue for 1 character past its max length restriction?

Tags: javascript

In an input box I used `e.preventDefault();` to stop text input after `inputValue.length > 10`.  However text input always stops at 11 characters instead of 10.  I can't understand why it doesn't stop accepting characters at 10.  Why is this?  Thanks so much!

```js
'use strict';
 
document.querySelectorAll('.input_style')[0].addEventListener('keydown', pressKey); 
document.querySelectorAll('.input_style')[0].addEventListener('keyup', releaseKey);

function pressKey(e) {
  let inputValue = e.target.value;  
  if (inputValue.length > 10) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

function releaseKey(e) {
  let inputValue = e.target.value;
  console.log(inputValue.length);
  if (inputValue.length > 10 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
.input_style {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<input class="input_style">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of the string has to be 11 for the condition > 10 to be true.  If you want to stop at 10, do >= 10.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition waits until it's **bigger than** 10, so that condition is only met when it's 11.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that new values are added to the `input` on `keydown`, not `keyup`, and your `keydown` handler `pressKey(e)` is checking for the **current value of the input box, before adding the new value**.  Therefore, you need to check for your `length >= 10` rather than `>10`.

The `keyup` handler in this case is completely unnecessary, since it does not stop a new value from being added.

Another thing you should consider is checking for the input `keycode` values `8` (`"backspace"`) and `46` (`"delete"`), and allow those to be handled.  As it stands now, once your input box is full, it is impossible to change it in any way, as you can't use <kbd>backspace</kbd> or <kbd>delete</kbd> to remove a wrong character.